# Ошибка: нет индексного свойства по умолчанию для типа char

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Не могу понять в чём проблема(строка указана)

```
var
  i: char;
  j: integer;
  s: string;
  x: boolean;

begin
  writeln('Введите строку:');
  readln(s);
  for i := char[33] to char[255] do{Тут пишет:нет индексного свойства по умолчанию для типа char}
  begin
    x := false;
    for j := 1 to length(s) do
    begin
      if i = s[j] then
      begin
        if not x then 
          write(i, ' - ');
          write(s[j], ' ');
          flag:=true
      end;
      if x then writeln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i := char(33) to char(255) do
```

или

```
for i := chr(33) to chr(255) do
```